# How to add data to ObservableCollection in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, observablecollection

I have a table in my databse called Impacts, and it has two foring keys called
cmpt_name and cmpt_reference  from Component Table.

and i want to add some data to a ObservableCollection which i created using Impact table.
But i cant add cmpt_name and cmpt_reference to it ?

```
public ObservableCollection<Impact> ModelListe { get; set; }

private Impact model;

public Project_Questions_Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ModelListe = new ObservableCollection<Impact>();
    DataContext = this;
}

public void addData()
{
     model = new Impact();
     **model.Component.cmpt_name = comboBoxComponents.Text;**
     model.impt_name = textBoxQuestion.Text;
     **model.Component.cmpt_reference = comboBoxComponents.SelectedValuePath;**
     ModelListe.Add(model);
}
```

I get error in highlighted line it says:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can any one tell me how to solve it please?
Im using entity model database.

Comment: Can you show me your `Impact class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you new up an `Impact` instance I'm pretty sure it does not contain a `Component` yet. So `model.Component` is the null object here.

I don't know your business logic but I assume the remedy is to fetch `Component`s from the database and populate the combobox with these pre-existing components. Now when you create a new `Impact` you don't set its component's name, but you set its `Compenent` property:

```
model.Component = comboBoxComponents.SelectedValue;
```